# Python: Determine the number of thread to make

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10055] An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

How do I determine the number of thread instances I should make in order to prevent my program from encountering the above error?

```
def do_work(sym):
    if quote.get_price(i) != '0.00':
        print '%s: %s' % (i, squote.get_price(i))

for i in perm:
    t = Thread(target=do_work, args=(i,))
    t.start()
```

Note:
1. len(perm) is about 27000
2. quote.get_price() does something similar to:

```
return urllib.urlopen(url).read().strip().strip('"')
```

Comment: Why are you spawning 27,000 threads in the first place?

Comment: Do you really want to read 27000 webpages in parallel? That sounds problematic even if you spawned the threads.

Comment: @exantas the point of this question is not that i want to spawn 27000 threads. its about trying to determine what is the optimal number of threads to spawn. How do I determine that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use thread pool instead of creating 27,000 threads.

```
import multiprocessing.pool

def do_work(sym):
    if quote.get_price(sym) != '0.00':
        print '%s: %s' % (sym, squote.get_price(sym))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_threads = 4
    pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(number_of_threads)
    pool.map(do_work, perm)
```

Comment: why 4? why not 3,5,6,7,8,9 or so forth?

Comment: @antz, 4 is number of core in my machine. You need to investigate which number is best for your task.

Comment: @antz, If you don't pass anything to `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, it will default to the number of the cores.

Comment: ah i see. that makes sense. i get this error.    pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(number_of_threads)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pool'. i have python 2.7.3

Comment: @antz, Make sure to import `multiprocessing.pool`, not `multiprocessing`.

Comment: okay great! that fixed it. and its a lot faster than doing it in a loop. nice.

Answer (score 2):

The overhead of 27,000 threads is likely what is causing your problem. Try instead creating a queue of the stocks you want to receive quotes for and use a worker pool of 5-10 threads to retrieve the prices.

Comment: where did the number 5-10 came from? why that range?

Comment: @antz It's based on experience. It could be wrong. You'll want to experiment if efficiency is important to you.

Comment: could you elaborate how to conduct that experiment? is it just come up with a number and compare how it perform against one another?